# Javascript - Promises stay as pending

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

Why do my promises stay in the pending state and how do I fix it?

```
    var foundPeopleA = findPeopleA().then(function(result) {
        var res = []
        result.map(function(el) {
            res.push(getProfileXML(el.sid));
        });
        return res
    });

    var foundPeopleB = findPeopleB().then(function(result) {
        var res = []
        result.map(function(el) {
            res.push(getProfileXML(el.sid));
        });
        return res
    })

    return Promise.all([findPeopleA, findPeopleB]).then(function(results) {
        console.log(results) //[ [ Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> } ],  [ Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> } ] ]
    })
```

However if i change the body of the 2 functions above into

```
        var res
        result.map(function(el) {
            res = getProfileXML(el.sid);
        });
        return res
```

they won't be pending and I'll get the result.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are not promises. If you return an array of promises, `then` gets an array of promises - just like if you return any other non-promise value. Only if you return a promise, the promise will get executed before `then`. Your `foundPeopleA` and `foundPeopleB` each construct an array of promises; you need to concatenate those arrays and pass them to `Promise.all` or equivalent in order to get them executed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are handling the promises fulfillment on each of them individually by using `then`, and `all` handles the fulfillment of multiple promises by passing it an array of *unresolved* promises. It builds a new promise with the results of all of them together. Just use:

```
Promise.all([findPeopleA(), findPeopleB()])
.then(function(responses) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning your Array to the result of the mapping.

```
var foundPeopleA = findPeopleA().then(function(result) {
    var res = []
    res = result.map(function(el) {
        return getProfileXML(el.sid);
    });
    return res
});
```

Or, perhaps you can resolve the promise?

```
var foundPeopleA = findPeopleA().then(function(result) {
    var res = []
    res = result.map(function(el) {
        return getProfileXML(el.sid);
    });
    resolve(res);
});
```

Either way, I belive you need to build your array by returning values from the mapping to create the new array.

Comment: First one gives the same output and second one doesn't even reach the next execution, can't get output.

Comment: What do you mean "same output"?

Comment: One I mentioned in the question. //[ [ Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> } ],  [ Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> } ] ]